# How to compute modular reduction in CRT domain?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm working with big integers using chinese remainder theorem (CRT). This way I can map some big integer in a set of small ones.

I have addition and multiplication simply applying it coefficient-wise. However, modular reduction doesn't work so simply.

**What I want to do:** 
Let $a$, $q$, $p$ integers and $ a > q > p$. I know $a \mod p$ and I know $q$ and $p$. How to compute $\left(a \mod q\right) \mod p$?

**What I have tried:**

$$a \mod q = a - \lfloor \frac{a}{q}\rfloor \cdot q$$

So,
$$a \mod q \mod p = \left[ a \mod p - \left(\lfloor \frac{a}{q}\rfloor \mod p\right)\cdot \left(q \mod p\right)\right] \mod p.$$

I know $a\mod p$ and $q \mod p$ but I can't compute $\lfloor \frac{a}{q}\rfloor$ since I don't know a.

**Question:**
How to compute $a \mod q \mod p$ only knowing $a \mod p$, $q$ and $p$?

Answer (score 1):

You are on a fool's errand. Let $p = 5$ and $q = 2$. Now

$$6 \equiv 1 \mod 5 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 6 \equiv 0 \mod 2$$
and
$$11 \equiv 1 \mod 5 \qquad\text{and}\qquad11 \equiv 1 \mod 2$$

Thus you see that knowing $a \mod p$ is not enough to determine $a \mod q$ or $ (a\mod q) \mod p$.

---

I apparently missed the $a > q > p$ condition. However, this is still not solvable. Letting $q = 5$ and $p = 2$, suppose we know that $a \equiv 1 \mod 2$. Some possibilities are

- $a = 1, \ a \equiv 1 \mod 5, \ (a \mod 5) \equiv 1 \mod 2$
- $a = 7, \ a \equiv 2 \mod 5, \ (a \mod 5) \equiv 0 \mod 2$

Thus neither $a \mod q$ nor $(a \mod q) \mod p$ are well-defined.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow you. Could you clarify that, please? How your example shows that?

Comment: As per your edit of the original question, I also had to swap $p$ and $q$ to match. If you know that $a \equiv 1 \mod 5$, then $6$ and $11$ are both candidates for $a$, but $6 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $11 \equiv 1 \mod 2$. So if $p = 5$ and $q = 2$, we see that knowing $a \equiv 1 \mod p$ is not sufficient to determine $a \mod q$, which can be either $1$ or $0$. (and further modding by $p$ doesn't change that).

Comment: I'm forcing that $ a > q > p$. So, swapping p and q from your example I know that $a \equiv 1 \mod p = 1 \mod 2$, what takes me to $a = 11$. Now it works for this example, but as we know there is infinity integers equivalent to $ 1 \mod 2$, so I have sure there is some other value for $a$ that fails on this test. I think you may be right. However, how can CRT recover the right value for a? Can't we use the same idea here?

Comment: I added an edit to exactly fit your conditions. I forgot about the $a > q > p$ condition when I changed the original example in response to your changing $\mod q$ to $\mod p$. CRT gives you values of $x$ that satisfy both $x \equiv x_1 \mod p$ and $x \equiv x_2 \mod q$ at the same time, given $p, q, x_1, x_2$. What you have is different. You only know $x_1$ and are wanting to figure out $x_2$, up to modulus, from it. But as the example shows (and it is simple to come up with more), that just isn't enough information. No technique can change that. You need stronger conditions.

Comment: Actually I'm working under the conditions of CRT. What I want is find a function $F$ so that $F\left(CRT(x),q\right) = CRT\left(x \mod q\right)$.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the problem comes from, or what methods you use. Without additional information beyond the givens here, $(a\mod q)\mod p$ can have multiple values (in fact, any multiple of the gcd of $p$ and $q$). So you cannot solve for it.